# Map 2D matrix to 1D array

Tags: java, c++, arrays, matrix

I have two containers: a 2-dimensional NxN matrix and a 1-dimensional array which is the transposed 1D "version" of the matrix (so for a 5x5 array, I will have a 25 element array with the same values). I want to implement a query function that will take 2D coordinates as arguments but will be doing work on the equivalent 1D array.

In order to keep algorithm efficiency strictly non-quadratic I want to access only the array and not the matrix.

I've checked other questions but they all talk about converting the whole matrix to an array through nested for-loops. I don't want to do this, as that would take quadratic time to run. Instead, I want the conversion to be on-demand for a given coordinate through a query function/method. In other words for a given number of N columns/rows:

```
transpose(int i, int j) {
    int result;

    result = i * N + j;
    return result;
}
```

This is the formula I'm using but it is not correct. For example if I want to access the element in the {5,5} position the result would be 5*5 + 5 = 30, which is greater than 25 (which would be the total number of elements for 5x5 matrix).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by *equivalent 1D array*, how are 1D and 2D arrays related?

Comment: Maybe "analogous" would be a better word? They are not related in general, but I'm pretty sure there is a formula for "converting" or "mapping" a 2D matrix to a 1D array.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific, i cannot try to guess what you have in your mind. Do you mean something like transposing a 10X10 matrix in a 100 elements array?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have in mind.

Comment: and what do you mean by *I want the conversion to be on-demand for a given coordinate*?

Comment: I'm editing the question for clarity. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: @AutomEng `if I want to access the element in the {5,5} position the result would be 5*5 + 5 = 30`  Arrays start at element 0, not 1. `{0,0}` will get you the element in the first row, first column, `{1,1}` is the second row, second column, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `2d` array and a `1d` array having same elements,then the following will be true

```
  2d[i][j]=1d[i*number_of_columns+j]
```

I am assuming from your post that you already have created a 1d array out of a 2d one.
Note `i` and `j` are indices and rememeber indices begin from `0`

EDIT:If you are accessing an element at `[5][5]` (as last element)it means your array is of order `6 by 6` and not `5 by 5`.So your 1d array will have `6*6=36` elements and not `25`.

Comment: As I wrote in my edited question this produces out of bounds results for a NxN matrix. This is what I've been trying to do myself, but keep getting out array index out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: @AutomEng.Note that if you have a `5 by 5` matrix there would be no element arr[5][5].last element would be at [4][4].Tell me if that made sense

Comment: It did, yes. A mistake on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `deepToString()` method to output a 2D array to a String.  This can make it easier to do things such as `sort()` for example.

Comment: Then make a 1D array out of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a declared `int mat2d[m][n];` with `m` rows and `n` columns, you can convert it like

```
int * mat1d = new int[m * n];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++i)
        mat1d[k++] = mat2d[i][j];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert between 1D and 2D coordinates, serve yourself and make  functions from this:

```
const int width = 10;

// from 1D coordinate to 2D coordinate
int coord_1d = 25;
int coord_x = coord_1d % width;
int coord_y = coord_1d / width;

// from 2D coordinate to 1D coordinate
coord_1d = coord_x + coord_y * width;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing, you said that you don't want nested loops, here is a just-one-loop conversion

```
    int[][] a={
            {1,2,3,4,5,6},
            {4,5,6,7,8,9},
            {7,8,9,1,2,3},
            {1,2,3,4,5,6}
            };
    int[]b=new int[a.length*a[0].length];

    int x=0;
    for(int i=0, j=0;i<a.length&&j<a[0].length;i=(j==a[0].length-1?i+1:i),j=(j+1)%a[0].length)
        b[x++]=a[i][j];

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

If you want the conversion to be based on coordinates, by changing `i` and `j` values in the for loop to such coordinates will allow you to convert to array only a subset of your matrix